# Impact of total stress tensor's definition on a continuum's linear momentum equation derivation and result

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, conservation-laws, navier-stokes

I am reading the book: *"The Finite
Volume Method
in Computational
Fluid Dynamics
An Advanced Introduction with
OpenFOAM® and Matlab®"* - DOI 10.1007/978-3-319-16874-6

The section of concern is the derivation of the conservative form of the linear momentum.

The book defines the total stress tensor as:

$\mathbf{\sum} = \begin{bmatrix}\sum_{xx} && \sum_{xy} && \sum_{xz} \\
\sum_{yx} && \sum_{yy} && \sum_{yz} \\
\sum_{zx} && \sum_{zy} && \sum_{zz} \end{bmatrix} = -p\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{\tau}$

where $\sum_{i,j}$ is the force acting on face $i$ in the $j$ direction, $p$ is pressure and $\tau$ is the deviatoric stress tensor.

On page 54 the following statement is made:

> The surface force acting on a differential surface element of area
> $dS$ and orientation $\mathbf{n}$, as illustrated in figure 3.5, is
> ($\mathbf{\sum} \cdot \mathbf{n})dS$. Applying the divergence theorem,
> the total surface force acting on the control volume is given by:
> $\int_{V} \mathbf{f}_{s} dV = \int_{S} \mathbf{\sum} \cdot \mathbf{n} dS = \int_{V} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\sum} dV$
>
> [image]

However, after doing a sanity check, I am getting confused. For a surface element facing the positive $x$ direction defined by $\mathbf{n} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ then by the definition provided for the dot product of tensor and vector provided in the book (page 30) the force vector would be:

$\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{xx} && \sum_{xy} && \sum_{xz} \\
\sum_{yx} && \sum_{yy} && \sum_{yz} \\
\sum_{zx} && \sum_{zy} && \sum_{zz} \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_{xx} \\ \sum_{yx} \\\sum_{zx} \end{bmatrix}$.

This does not make sense to me. This says the force on a surface facing the positive $x$ direction but contains $\sum_{yx}$ and $\sum_{zx}$ terms which are only present on the $y$ and $z$ facing surfaces respectively.

Perhaps they are assuming a symmetric stress tensor? However, I understand that this is not always the case which is the reason for my hesitancy to move forward with that assumption.

**Question:** Should the surface force on a differential surface element of area $dS$ instead be:

$(\mathbf{\sum}^{T} \cdot \mathbf{n})dS$

which would then give:

$\int_{V} \mathbf{f}_{s} dV = \int_{S} \mathbf{\sum}^{T} \cdot \mathbf{n}dS = \int_{V} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\sum}^{T} dV$

resulting in $\mathbf{f}_{s} = \nabla \cdot \sum^{T} = -\nabla p + \nabla \cdot \tau^{T}$

giving the conservative linear momentum equation as:

$\frac{\partial \rho \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf{vv}) = -\nabla p + \nabla \cdot \tau^{T} + \mathbf{f}_{b}$

where $\mathbf{f}_{s}$ is surface forces and $\mathbf{f}_{b}$ is body forces.

Have I missed the mark? Is the reason why some stress tensors are defined instead with $\sum_{i,j}$ being the stress in direction $i$ in on face $j$ to prevent carrying the transpose?

Answer (score 1):

After reading Claudio's answer, I read further on the theory of traction vectors and stress tensors. I believe I have derived a way of proving that the surface force on the surface element of surface area $dS$ should, in fact, be $(\sum^{T} \cdot \mathbf{n})dS$.

Consider the stress tensor defined on the element below with lengths $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$.

[image]

The total stress tensor is defined as:

$\sum = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{T}_{1} \\ \mathbf{T}_{2} \\ \mathbf{T}_{3} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\sum_{xx} && \sum_{xy} && \sum_{xz} \\
\sum_{yx} && \sum_{yy} && \sum_{yz} \\
\sum_{zx} && \sum_{zy} && \sum_{zz} \end{bmatrix} = -p\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{\tau}$

Performing a conservation on linear momentum in the $x$ direction gives rise to the equation:

$\mathbf{T}_{x} - [(\mathbf{T}_{1} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}})dydz + (\mathbf{T}_{2} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}})dxdz + (\mathbf{T}_{3} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}})dydx] \hat{\mathbf{x}} = \rho \space dx \space dy \space dz \space \mathbf{a}_{x}$

Let $dx = dy = dz$ Then $dA = dydz = dxdz = dxdy$

$\mathbf{T}_{x} - [(\mathbf{T}_{1} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}})dA + (\mathbf{T}_{2} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}})dA + (\mathbf{T}_{3} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}})dA] \hat{\mathbf{x}} = \rho \space dx \space dy \space dz \space \mathbf{a}_{x}$

$\mathbf{T}_{x} - [(\mathbf{T}_{1} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}) + (\mathbf{T}_{2} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}) + (\mathbf{T}_{3} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}})] \hat{\mathbf{x}} = \rho \space \frac{dx \space dy \space dz}{dA} \space \mathbf{a}_{x}$

Let $dydz$ cancel with $dA$ and let $dx \rightarrow 0$ to make it a plane normal to the $x$ axis.

$\mathbf{T}_{x} = [(\mathbf{T}_{1} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}) + (\mathbf{T}_{2} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}) + (\mathbf{T}_{3} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}})]\hat{\mathbf{x}} = [(\mathbf{T}_{1} + \mathbf{T}_{2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}]\hat{\mathbf{x}}$

This gives the traction vector which conserves the momentum of the positive $dydz$ face as the element is squished into the blue plane below.

[image]

This can then be done for all $y$ and $z$ directions, defining the force vectors required on each of the faces of the element at the intersection of the three planes shown in the figure above to conserve momentum in each of the orthogonal directions.

This gives us the equations:

$\mathbf{T}_{x} = [(\mathbf{T}_{1} + \mathbf{T}_{2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}]\hat{\mathbf{x}}$

$\mathbf{T}_{y} = [(\mathbf{T}_{1} + \mathbf{T}_{2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{y}}]\hat{\mathbf{y}}$

$\mathbf{T}_{z} = [(\mathbf{T}_{1} + \mathbf{T}_{2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{z}}]\hat{\mathbf{z}}$

Then to conserve the element's momentum in direction $\mathbf{n}$ will result in:
$\mathbf{T}_{n} = \big( [(\mathbf{T}_{1} + \mathbf{T}_{2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}]\hat{\mathbf{x}} + [(\mathbf{T}_{1} + \mathbf{T}_{2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{y}}]\hat{\mathbf{y}} + [(\mathbf{T}_{1} + \mathbf{T}_{2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{z}}]\hat{\mathbf{z}} \big) \cdot \mathbf{n}$

$= [(\mathbf{T}_{1,1} + \mathbf{T}_{2,1}  + \mathbf{T}_{3,1}) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}} + (\mathbf{T}_{1,2} + \mathbf{T}_{2,2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3,2} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{y}} + (\mathbf{T}_{1,3} + \mathbf{T}_{2,3}  + \mathbf{T}_{3,3} ) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{z}}] \cdot \mathbf{n}$

$= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{T}_{1,1} + \mathbf{T}_{2,1}  + \mathbf{T}_{3,1} 
\\ \mathbf{T}_{1,2} + \mathbf{T}_{2,2}  + \mathbf{T}_{3,2}  \\
\mathbf{T}_{1,3} + \mathbf{T}_{2,3}  + \mathbf{T}_{3,3} \end{bmatrix} \cdot \mathbf{n}$

$= \begin{bmatrix}\sum_{xx} && \sum_{yx} && \sum_{zx} \\
\sum_{xy} && \sum_{yy} && \sum_{zy} \\
\sum_{xz} && \sum_{yz} && \sum_{zz} \end{bmatrix} \cdot \mathbf{n}$

$= \sum^{T} \cdot \mathbf{n}$

as stated.

---

"**Backup**"

As "evidence" to back up this approach, the article on [Wikipedia regarding Cauchy's Stress Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor), which defines the total stress tensor in the same way, defines the traction vector as $\mathbf{T}^{T} = \mathbf{n}^{T} \sum$. This is equal to the statement, $\mathbf{T} = \sum^{T} \cdot \mathbf{n}$.

Further, the result of applying the divergence theorem over a surface $S$ provides the same result:

$\displaystyle\int\limits_{S} {\textstyle\sum^{T}} \cdot \mathbf{n} dS = \int\limits_{V} \nabla \cdot {\textstyle\sum^{T}} dV = \int\limits_{V} {\textstyle\sum_{ji,j}} dV$

When the volume is shrunk to an element it provides the same result as the article in the absence of body forces for a direction:

$\sum_{ji,j} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

I understand that any portion of the total volume can be limited by a boundary like that indicated. In this case, the definition of traction force as $\delta \mathbf T = \sigma \mathbf n dS$ is valid. $\sigma$ is the stress state in the point.

That traction force acts in a elementary volume $dxdydz$, and has contributions of all the face stresses. So in your example: $\delta T = (\sigma_{xx}, \sigma_{yx}, \sigma_{zx})dS$

I believe that it is not correct to see the macroscopic boundary $S$ as corresponding also to a boundary for each volume element. In this case we are puzzled by a face $dS$ that also corresponds to a face $dydz$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Claudio; it got me reading further into the stress tensors and traction vectors. After additional reading, I have come to the conclusion that the correction statement I have made is correct. I have added my reasoning to an answer below.